# if a function belongs to the a space $H_0^1(\Omega)$, then could this function belong to the dual space $H^{-1}(\Omega)$..

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, hilbert-spaces

The weak form of the given PDE with approximate solution $u^m$  is as
\begin{align}\label{semi1}
  (u^m_{t},\chi)+\alpha(u^m_x,\chi_x)+\beta (f(u^m),\chi)=0,~\forall \chi\in V_m.    
 \end{align} with
\begin{equation*}
u^m (0)=u_0^m.
\end{equation*}
$V_m$  is the finite dimensional subspace of $H_0^1(\Omega)$ and $f(u)$ is the nonlinear term.

**My question is** :
To show the the boundedness of $||u^m||_{H^1}$ can we choose   $\chi=u^m_t$, where $u(x,t)\in L^{2}(0,T;H_0^1(\Omega))$ and $u_t(x,t)\in L^{2}(0,T;H^{-1}(\Omega))$.

**As I think**, due to $H_0^1(\Omega)\subset L^2(\Omega)\subset H^{-1}(\Omega)$, we can choose.

Can someone clear regarding this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.